# getting the string values from controller to the Visual force component

Tags: apex, javascript, visualforce-component

I want a value from the controller in the component using the java script , but i am new to this so i don't know how to achieve it. this is my controller class.

```
    public with sharing class DragAndDropMultipleDirect
      {
          Public string orgID {get;set;}
          Public string userID {get;set;}
          Public string s3path {get;set;}
          public DragAndDropMultipleDirect()
           {

           }

public String path()
{
    String orgID = UserInfo.getOrganizationId() ;
    String userID =UserInfo.getUserId();
    String s3path ='string/'+orgID+'/'+userID;
    system.debug('orgID ==== ???  '+s3path);
    return s3path;

}
```

I want the value of s3path in the script of the component.

```
<apex:component Controller="DragAndDropMultipleDirect">
     <apex:attribute name="parentId" type="String" description="Parent record"/>
  <Script>
       function readfiles(files) { 
               var path = **Here i Want the value of s3Path**
                 ----- code----
        }
 </Script>
</apex:component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you controller you are setting values of local variables not the properties and also never calling the method that does that work.

Instead use the constructor so that the fields are always set whenever the object is created:

```
public with sharing class DragAndDropMultipleDirect
{
    Public string orgID {get; set;}
    Public string userID {get; set;}
    Public string s3path {get; set;}

    public DragAndDropMultipleDirect()
    {
        orgID = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
        userID = UserInfo.getUserId();
        s3path = 'string/' + orgID + '/' + userID;
    }
}
```

Then in the JavaScript:

```
<apex:page Controller="DragAndDropMultipleDirect">
<Script>
var path = '{! JSENCODE(s3path) }';
alert(path);
</Script>
</apex:page>
```

The quotes are needed to create a valid JavaScript string and the JSENCODE ensures that any characters that need escaping in a JavaScript string are escaped.

Comment: Keith, thanks I have used your code but when I check this in alert in java script there is no value for the path. do you know why is it so?

Comment: @HarishChauhan I just tried exactly the code now in the question and the alert worked. There was a `}` instead of a `)` in the original version of the answer that is fixed now in the answer. When working with JavaScript always check your browser's console for JavaScript errors.

Comment: yes I have corrected this. Thanks code worked for me.